# How can i set Right to Left direction in xamarin.form the same as process which is used in flowdirection in wpf

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App10.Page1"  >
    <ContentPage.Conte`FlowDirection` >

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

How can i set Right to Left direction in xamarin.form the same as process which is used in flowdirection in wpf

Comment: Don't think you can https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24831/change-flow-direction-of-a-content-page

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , As far as I know until now , there is not a property to set flowdirection in Xamarin.Form .

So I think you may use other methods to layout your view such as RelativeLayout 
and set a relative position to make the view right to left in the XAML or in the c# code. I think it is more flexible.

The document of using RelativeLayout :

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/